# Shared API with Separate Sessions

Tags: express, web-services, http, cross-domain

I have an API & React app running under localhost:4000 (app A) and I want to access app A's API from a second React app localhost:3000 (app B). I configured CORS correctly to allow app B to send requests to app A with credentials.

However, it appears that app A and app B are sharing cookies, that is if I log in on app A, I will be also logged in on app B. Most of the time this is what you want and I have seen many questions along the lines of "How do I share cookies cross-domain". My question is different because I want to **not** share cookies cross-domain, I would like each domain to have their own set of cookies.

Is this possible?

I'm using [express cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and my configuration for the API on app A looks like the following:

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
    credentials: true
  }))
```

My requests from app B (localhost:3000) look like the following:

```js
const transport = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache' }, //prevent IE11 cacheing
  })

transport.get('http://localhost:4000/api/user')
```

Again app B has access to app A's cookies within the same browser, which is not what I want. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both APIs are using the same cookie mechanism (express `cookie-session`), you might want to use separate cookie names in each application.

For example:

```js
// in app A
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'sessionA',
}))
```

```js
// in app B
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'sessionB',
}))
```

In this example, App A could read B's cookies (and vice versa), but they would be stored separately. If you need the cookie to be protected from reading via the other app, you may want to explore using a different `secret` for each app's cookie configuration as well. [These docs explain the `keys` and `secret` options](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html).

Or if using `express-session`:

https://github.com/expressjs/session#name

> Note if you have multiple apps running on the same hostname (this is just the name, i.e. localhost or 127.0.0.1; different schemes and ports do not name a different hostname), then you need to separate the session cookies from each other. The simplest method is to simply set different names per app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am using `express-session`, but it has a similar interface. I verified that both secrets are different from my express apps. However, I am getting the same result of the cookies being shared. When I log in on from app A, I appear logged in on app B, vice versa.

Comment: Oh, that library is different. Have you tried setting a different `name` between the two apps? https://github.com/expressjs/session#name

> Note if you have multiple apps running on the same hostname (this is just the name, i.e. localhost or 127.0.0.1; different schemes and ports do not name a different hostname), then you need to separate the session cookies from each other. The simplest method is to simply set different names per app.

Comment: I tried setting different `name`s with no luck. I also tried opening the react app B from a different host (ie `http://127.0.0.1:3000`), but it was still sending the cookies from app A in the API calls to A. It seems that there's no way for app A to access app B's cookies or set them.

The answer is I needed to put app A on a separate hostname and make calls to it. In this case, I used `http://127.0.0.1:4000`. This will create a separate set of cookies. It's not super ideal as I'll have to make an alias domain that points to the app A's API in production (ie api.appA.com).